# JAVA 8 Reference to instance methods. How does vals[i] automatically mapped to this in "InstanceMethWithObjectRefDemo.counter"

Tags: java, java-8

I'm Reading a java Book from it I got this code. I know how method references are made but this one is giving me a headache. I have no idea how `vals[i]` in `if(f.func(vals[i], v))` acts as `this` for mapped function.

```
// Use an instance method reference with different objects. 
// A functional interface that takes two reference arguments 
// and returns a boolean result.
interface MyFunc<T> { 
    boolean func(T v1, T v2); 
}
// A class that stores the temperature high for a day. 
class HighTemp { 
    private int hTemp; 
    HighTemp(int ht) {
    hTemp = ht;
} 

// Return true if the invoking HighTemp object has the same 
// temperature as ht2.
boolean sameTemp(HighTemp ht2) { 
    return hTemp == ht2.hTemp; 
}
// Return true if the invoking HighTemp object has a temperature 
// that is less than ht2. 
boolean lessThanTemp(HighTemp ht2) { 
    return hTemp < ht2.hTemp; 
} 
} 
class InstanceMethWithObjectRefDemo { 
// A method that returns the number of occurences 
// of an object for which some criteria, as specified by 
// the MyFunc parameter, is true. 
static <T> int counter(T[] vals, MyFunc<T> f, T v) { 
    int count = 0; 
    for(int i=0; i < vals.length; i++) {
    if(f.func(vals[i], v)) count++; 
    }
    return count;   
} 

public static void main(String args[]) { 
    int count;
    // Create an array of HighTemp objects. 
    HighTemp[] weekDayHighs = { new HighTemp(89), new HighTemp(82), 
                            new HighTemp(90), new HighTemp(89), 
                            new HighTemp(89), new HighTemp(91), 
                            new HighTemp(84), new HighTemp(83) }; 

    // Use counter() with arrays of the class HighTemp. 
    // Notice that a reference to the instance method 
    // sameTemp() is passed as the second argument. 
    count = counter(weekDayHighs, HighTemp::sameTemp,new HighTemp(89)); 
    System.out.println(count + " days had a high of 89"); 

    // Now, create and use another array of HighTemp objects. 
    HighTemp[] weekDayHighs2 = { new HighTemp(32), new HighTemp(12), 
                            new HighTemp(24), new HighTemp(19), 
                            new HighTemp(18), new HighTemp(12), 
                            new HighTemp(-1), new HighTemp(13) }; 

    count = counter(weekDayHighs2, HighTemp::sameTemp,new HighTemp(12)); 
    System.out.println(count + " days had a high of 12"); 
    // Now, use lessThanTemp() to find days when temperature was less 
    // that a specified value.
    count = counter(weekDayHighs, HighTemp::lessThanTemp,new        HighTemp(89)); 
    System.out.println(count + " days had a high less than 89"); 
    count = counter(weekDayHighs2, HighTemp::lessThanTemp,new HighTemp(19)); 
    System.out.println(count + " days had a high of less than 19"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Look at the call: `new HighTemp(89)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context `HighTemp::sameTemp` is equivalent to `(t1, t2) -> t1.sameTemp(t2)`.

In the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) it is known as *Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type*

> The following is an example of a reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type:
>
> String[] stringArray = { "Barbara", "James", "Mary", "John",
>       "Patricia", "Robert", "Michael", "Linda" };
>   Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
>
> The equivalent lambda expression for the method reference String::compareToIgnoreCase would have the formal parameter list (String a, String b), where a and b are arbitrary names used to better describe this example. The method reference would invoke the method a.compareToIgnoreCase(b).

Comment: A correction. In this context HighTemp::sameTemp is equivalent to (t1, t2) -> t1.sameTemp(t2)